# MVC 3 Required annotation ErrorMessage text is not inserted into attribute data-val-required of my input tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a required property, with an errormessage, in my model and the errormessage text is not being shown when the user does not enter any text for this property.

My cshtml page is

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Booking", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <fieldset>

        <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerOrderNumber, "", "", new { @class = "control-label" }) 
            <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerOrderNumber) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerOrderNumber)
            <p class="help-block">This is a mandatory field.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </fieldset>

}
```

I've removed all extraneous content.

My model .cs source is

```
using System;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Technolog.Rma.Business.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RepairBatch
    { 

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a order number.")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name ="Order number")]
        public virtual string CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }

        public RepairBatch()
        {
            CustomerOrderNumber = "";
        }

        public virtual void copy(RepairBatch rb){
            this.CustomerOrderNumber = rb.CustomerOrderNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at the returned html in the browser I see the following html for my customer order number input box

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="CustomerOrderNumber">Order number</label> 
    <div class="controls">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="&amp;#39;CustomerOrderNumber&amp;#39; must not be empty." id="CustomerOrderNumber" name="CustomerOrderNumber" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomerOrderNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <p class="help-block">This is a mandatory field.</p>
    </div>
```

The data-val-required attribute has the canned text returned by the MVC 3 framework and not the errormessage I specified on the customerordernumber property using the required attribute.

I'm using Visual Studo 2010 SP1 with MVC 3 April 2011 Tools update. I'm also using nhibernate 3.2 and spring.net  1.3.2

Has anyone experienced this problem or have any suggestions?

20/11/2012 update

I used the following workaround to show the correct validation message

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerOrderNumber, new { data_val_required="Please enter an order number"}) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerOrderNumber)

Jabbar Azam

Answer (score 0):

I don't use either nhibernate or spring.net but I did notice that your `CustomerOrderNumber` property is virtual.  Is your model class one derived from `RepairBatch` rather than `RepairBatch` itself?  I don't believe data annotations are recognized when they're on a base class.  (Folks, tell me if I'm wrong about this!)

Comment: Hello Ann, nhibernate requires the property to be virtual. My thinking is that if the virtual statement was a problem the actual [Required] annotation wouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: Hm. You know, a lot of the attributes are assumed to be provided as part of a metadata class, not the class itself.  If you have time, you might try whipping up a metadata class for `RepairBatch` and see if that makes a difference.  Just a thought.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late reply. The weekend and the timezone got in the way. I created a metaclass for Repairbatch and am still getting the same error. However I have a hack(workaround) which I am going to try. I'll let you know what happens